# VLC, Totem etc very slow frame rate/choppy but Firefox VLC plugin works fine

Tags: video, vlc, framerate

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an Acer Aspire V7 (i7 Haswell CPU). Playing any kind of movie file mkv, mp4 etc on VLC or Totem is horribly choppy with very slow frame rate like the computer can't handle it properly. Weirdly though playing the same files in Firefox using the VLC plugin works absolutely fine. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having similar issues with VLC lately in 14.10. I use firefox with no plugin (all disabled) and mp4 plays fine as well. Switching to parole media player seems to work just great but not as many options as VLC (playback speed etc).

One thing you can do for your intel chip is to first install vdpaudrivers http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/adobe-flash-player-hardware.html and in your vlc settings there is an option for hardware acceleration. make sure that box is selected and you can even specify to use the VDPAU va gl acceleration if i'm not mistaken.

Here's how to install the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libvdpau-va-gl1
```

Another way to run VLC with hardware acceleration is to use the following command (after installing the drivers):

```
VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl vlc
```

or

```
VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl totem
```

or

```
VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl parole
```

It also helps to install the intel-linux-graphics installer. You can do that with the following commands:

```
wget https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Finally, it really doesn't hurt (it helps) to have all the opengl support you can find. The synaptic package manager can help you search for and locate opengl packages. Just **pay attention to what get's uninstalled** if anything and **never** accept changes before reviewing to make sure installing stuff isn't going to uninstall something important in the process.

more info: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Comment: Installing and running the intel-linux-graphics installer solved this for me! Thank you very much for your help and time, it's very much appreciated!